# PowerQuery Extract everything before alphabet from a column

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am cleaning data and trying to figure out what the best way to extract data from a column is? None of the variables are same length or format but I want to extract the first ALPHABET and everything BEFORE it. For example:

Sample Data: 12345A123; 23456B000; 45678D93

Output: 12345A; 23456B; 45678D

Comment: did anyone's answer work for you?

Comment: @horseyride pretty much all of them did. All try a different way but they work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you really did a search for this. [It's in Microsoft's documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/splitcolumns-nondigit-to-digit)

I started with your list:

```
12345A123
23456B000
45678D93
```

Then I clicked on "Transform", "Split Column", then "Non-Digit to Digit". As a last step, I removed the second column the split produced.

[image: Screenshot of Power Query]

This is the output:

```
12345A
23456B
45678D
```

And here is the M code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Split Column by Character Transition" = Table.SplitColumn(Source, "Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByCharacterTransition((c) => not List.Contains({"0".."9"}, c), {"0".."9"}), {"Column1.1", "Column1.2"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Split Column by Character Transition",{"Column1.2"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

[image]

Add a custom column and type in:

```
Splitter.SplitTextByCharacterTransition({"A".."Z", "a".."z"}, {"0".."9"})([Column1]){0}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about adding column, custom column, with formula

```
 = Text.Range([Column1],0,Text.PositionOfAny([Column1],{"a".."z","A".."Z"})+1)
```